# Creational pattern for generic objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, asp.net-core-2.1

could someone please help with the best way of returning the concrete implementation in the following scenarios. Say I have:

```
public interface IThing<TInput> where TInput : RequestBase
{
    string Process(T input);
}
```

And then multiple implementations:

```
public class Thing1<T> : IThing<T> where T : ReqThing1
public class Thing2<T> : IThing<T> where T : ReqThing2
```

In my calling class what is the best way of wrapping the construction of those classes and returning the IThing that I want in a clean, testable way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want, but here's an idea:

```
public abstract class RequestBase
{
}

public class ReqThing1 : RequestBase
{
}

public class ReqThing2 : RequestBase
{
}

public interface IThing<T> where T : RequestBase
{
    string Process(T input);
}

public class Thing1 : IThing<ReqThing1>
{
    public string Process(ReqThing1 input)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Thing2 : IThing<ReqThing2>
{
    public string Process(ReqThing2 input)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thing1 = new Thing1();
        var thing2 = new Thing2();
    }
}
```